# usemethod error in filter when filtering a dataset within shiny server

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, shiny, reactive

I was trying to code a shiny application that loads a Rdata based on the input of the users, filters it, and graphs the result. All Rdata files are located in a folder and follow the same name format. Here is the example of my code for the server.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({load(paste0("themewise_final_datasets/final_", input$Theme, "_theme.RData"))})
  data_filtered <- reactive({data() %>%
      filter(str_detect(locations, input$location))})

  output$average_tone_graph <- renderPlot({
    data_filtered() %>%
# below there were irrelevant code graphs.
```

The problem with this code is that even though the server loads the rdata, it doesn't filter it. I get the error UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character". I couldn't fix it. I thought it might be because the columns are factors and tried to fix that, but that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you try to apply a data type to a generic method like `filter` for which your system does not have a specific implementation. You can check what data types your environment supports (given the loaded packages) with ...

```
methods(filter)
```

At my system I get the result

```
#' [1] filter.data.frame* filter.ts*
```

which means, that I can apply the filter method on base R data frames and time series objects. Something similar seems to be the case on your system. From the error message you can learn that the input you provide for `filter` is of class `character`. If `methods(filter)` does not return a method for those, you have two options: find an implementation for `filter` that can handle character vectors; change the type of `data()`; or use a different way to filter the vector like this:

```R
data()[str_detect(locations, input$location)]
```